# How to compare points from different Uid in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to compare points from different `uid`, one is receiver uid and another is sender uid. I want to retrive these points and want to compare these points so that I can decide the winner of day1, day2 and day3.
How is it possible either with cloud functions or on Android studio only. 
Please help me out.[image]

Comment: But how to retrieve these points in both sender and receiver side because they bot the have different uid's so how's it possible to retrieve with respect to their ui'd and to compare them.

Comment: I already go through that link but there is nothing related to my issue there we can only retrieve and save data into respective uid's but there is nothing about retrieving from different uid's. And according to me this can be done in cloud functions but don't know how to approach this.

Comment: Have you stored the challange id `-LExD...TXqP`?

Comment: @AlexMamo -LExD...TXqP it is the pushId for every new challenge. The thing I want that to compare the points from different uid's.

Comment: Let's say from all uid's? Is that correct?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes from all uid's but the thing is from both the uid present in the particular challenge pushId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference challengeRef = rootRef.child("Challenge");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int senderPointsDayOne = ds.child(senderId).child("points").child("Day1").getValue(Integer.class);
            int senderPointsDayTwo = ds.child(senderId).child("points").child("Day2").getValue(Integer.class);
            int senderPointsDayThree = ds.child(senderId).child("points").child("Day3").getValue(Integer.class);

            int receiverPointsDayOne = ds.child(receiverId).child("points").child("Day1").getValue(Integer.class);
            int receiverPointsDayTwo = ds.child(receiverId).child("points").child("Day2").getValue(Integer.class);
            int receiverPointsDayThree = ds.child(receiverId).child("points").child("Day3").getValue(Integer.class);

            int senderTotal = senderPointsDayOne + senderPointsDayTwo + senderPointsDayThree;
            int receiverTotal = receiverPointsDayOne + receiverPointsDayTwo + receiverPointsDayThree;

            if(senderTotal > receiverTotal) {
                //sender is the winner
            } else if (senderTotal < receiverTotal) {
                //receiver is the winner
            } else {
                //it's even
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
challengeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which `senderId` is the id of the sender and `receiverId` is the id of the receiver. This code gives you the winner of all days. If you want the winner per day, just change the logic and compare the results for the corresponding day.

**Edit:** As a conclusion, you cannot query your database without having the `senderId` and the `receiverId` for each play and for that I recommend you store them. The best practice is to store the matches in a new node named `matches`. Your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- matches
         |
         --- matchId
               |
               --- senderId: true
               |
               --- receiverId: true
```

In which the the `matchId` is actual the pushed id from the other node `-LExD...TXqP`. In this case, you need to query your database first to get the opponents (`senderId` and `receiverId`) and then to get the result as explained above. So basically you need to query your database twice.

Comment: your logic for comparing is fine but if suppose I am the sender then I can able to retrieve the points from my uid only how can sender retrieve the points from receiver uid and same goes for receiver. This is my major concern.

Comment: But I already have stored uid in Challenge Node do I have to create another node to store only uid of the users?

Comment: Yes. In order to use those id's you first need to have them, to be able to use them in your reference. So query your database to get as keys, the `senderId` and the `receiverId` and use those values in the above code. So it's about nested listeners. Give it a try and keep me posted.

Comment: Yes I have solved it but some class cast exceptions are coming for that so I am resolving that part but yes the thing is I am able to retrieve the sender and receiver uid by creating another node called match. So thanks man this solution make some sense to me.